# update the return data automatically in flask templates

Tags: javascript, python, json, opencv, flask

I am working on Yolov3, OpenCV,python and Flask. Here, I explain the details of usage for each item.

Yolov3 - To detect and recognize object in video input

Opencv - To capture images of detected object in video input.

Flask - As a web server since it's support python language.

**My objective** 
To develop application which able to captured the image of the object and update in the flask web directly or real-time

For your information, currently my system able to capture image and save in one folder which name as **images** by using OpenCv and python. you can refer the code below.

**opencv and python code to capture image of object detected**

```
for i in range(len(boxes)):
    if i in indexes:
         x,y,w,h = boxes[i]
         label = str(LABELS[class_ids[i]])
         confidence= confidences[i]
         color = colors[class_ids[i]]
         crop_img = image[y:y + h, x:x + w]
         imagesPath = "images/file_%d.jpg"%self.d
         cv2.imwrite(imagesPath, crop_img)
         self.d+=1
         cv2.rectangle(image,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),color,2)
         cv2.putText(image,label+" "+str(round(confidence,2)),(x,y+30),font,1,(255,255,255),2)
```

When the images successfully save in images folder. I convert all the images in to base64 and return as json in flask. Here I attach the python code in flask.

**Covert image to base64 and render in html templates**

```
@app.route("/images")
def get_images():
    directory = os.listdir('C:/Users/HP/Miniconda3/envs/count_vechicle/coding/images')
    os.chdir('C:/Users/HP/Miniconda3/envs/count_vechicle/coding/images')

    image_list= list()
    for file in directory:
        data = dict()
        base = os.path.basename(file)
        data["label"] = base
        open_file = open(file,'rb')
        image_read = open_file.read()
        image_64_encode = base64.encodebytes(image_read)
        data["data"] = image_64_encode.decode('ascii')
        image_list.append(data)    
    final_data = {'files':image_list}
    return render_template('images.html', final_data=final_data)
```

**images.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>yolo</title>
</head>
 <body>
   <h1 class="logo">Results</h1>
   <ul>
    {% for data in final_data.files %}
    <li>{{data.label}}</li>
    <img alt="embedded" src="data:image/jpg;base64,{{data.data}}"/>
    {% endfor %}
   </ul>

 </body>
</html>
```

**Problem and question**

I have two major problem here.

1) When i run my application, my application captured the images welly. But it's automatically stop when image.html page is open to display the picture. Why it's happen and how to solve this?

2) If the application able to capture image even i open the image.html page. What should i do to update my web directly or real-time?

Here I attach the full code. Because I have been works for many weeks but still not found the solution. Hope someone can helps. Let's me know if u need more information

**code**

**App.py**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, Response,jsonify
from camera import VideoCamera
import numpy as np
import os
import time
import detect as dt
from PIL import Image
import cv2
import base64
import json
from pprint import pprint

app = Flask(__name__)



def success_handle(output, status=200, mimetype='application/json'):
    return Response(output, status=status, mimetype=mimetype)

@app.route("/images")
def get_images():
    directory = os.listdir('C:/Users/HP/Miniconda3/envs/count_vechicle/coding/images')
    os.chdir('C:/Users/HP/Miniconda3/envs/count_vechicle/coding/images')

    flist = list()
    for file in directory:
        data = dict()
        base = os.path.basename(file)
        data["label"] = base
        open_file = open(file,'rb')
        image_read = open_file.read()
        image_64_encode = base64.encodebytes(image_read)
        data["data"] = image_64_encode.decode('ascii')
        flist.append(data)
    final_data = {'files':flist}
    return render_template('images.html', final_data=final_data)


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

def gen(camera):
    frame_id = 0
    while True:
        frame = camera.get_frame()
        yield (b'--frame\r\n'
               b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + frame + b'\r\n\r\n')

@app.route('/video_feed')
def video_feed():
    return Response(gen(VideoCamera()),
                    mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True)
```

**camera.py**

```
import cv2
import time
import os
import numpy as np

font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN
starting_time= time.time()
frame_id = 0
count = 0
d = 0

labelsPath = os.path.sep.join(["yolo-coco", "coco.names"])
weightsPath = os.path.sep.join(["yolo-coco", "yolov3.weights"])
configPath = os.path.sep.join(["yolo-coco", "yolov3.cfg"])
#imagesPath = 'C:/Users/HP/Miniconda3/envs/count_vechicle/coding/images/file_%d.jpg"%d'
labelsPath = os.path.sep.join(["yolo-coco", "coco.names"])
VideoPath = os.path.sep.join(["videos", "highway.mp4"])
LABELS = open(labelsPath).read().strip().split("\n")


net = cv2.dnn.readNet(configPath, weightsPath)

layer_names = net.getLayerNames()
outputlayers = [layer_names[i[0] - 1] for i in net.getUnconnectedOutLayers()]


colors= np.random.uniform(0,255,size=(len(LABELS),3))

class VideoCamera(object):
    def __init__(self):
        # Using OpenCV to capture from device 0. If you have trouble capturing
        # from a webcam, comment the line below out and use a video file
        # instead.
        self.video = cv2.VideoCapture(VideoPath)
        self.frame_id = 0
        self.d = 0
        # If you decide to use video.mp4, you must have this file in the folder
        # as the main.py.
        # self.video = cv2.VideoCapture('video.mp4')

    def __del__(self):
        self.video.release()


    def get_frame(self):
        success, image = self.video.read()
        # We are using Motion JPEG, but OpenCV defaults to capture raw images,
        # so we must encode it into JPEG in order to correctly display the
        # video stream.
        self.frame_id+=1
        #print(frame_id)

        height,width,channels = image.shape
        #print (frame.shape)
        #detecting objects
        blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(image,0.00392,(320,320),(0,0,0),True,crop=False) #reduce 416 to 320    


        net.setInput(blob)
        outs = net.forward(outputlayers)
        #print(outs)
        print(outs[1])

        #Showing info on screen/ get confidence score of algorithm in detecting an object in blob
        class_ids=[]
        confidences=[]
        boxes=[]

        for out in outs:
            #print(out)
            for detection in out:
                scores = detection[5:]
                class_id = np.argmax(scores)
                confidence = scores[class_id]
                print(confidence)
                if confidence > 0.8:
                    #object detected
                    center_x= int(detection[0]*width)
                    center_y= int(detection[1]*height)
                    w = int(detection[2]*width)
                    h = int(detection[3]*height)

                    #cv2.circle(img,(center_x,center_y),10,(0,255,0),2)
                    #rectangle co-ordinaters
                    x=int(center_x - w/2)
                    y=int(center_y - h/2)
                    #cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,0),2)

                    boxes.append([x,y,w,h]) #put all rectangle areas
                    confidences.append(float(confidence)) #how confidence was that object detected and show that percentage
                    class_ids.append(class_id) #name of the object tha was detected

        indexes = cv2.dnn.NMSBoxes(boxes,confidences,0.4,0.6)
        # result = open('C:/Users/HP/Miniconda3/envs/count_vechicle/coding/images/frame%04d.txt'%(count), 'w')
        for i in range(len(boxes)):
            if i in indexes:
                x,y,w,h = boxes[i]
                label = str(LABELS[class_ids[i]])
                # cv2.imwrite(label, crop_img)
                confidence= confidences[i]
                color = colors[class_ids[i]]
                crop_img = image[y:y + h, x:x + w]
                imagesPath = "images/file_%d.jpg"%self.d
                cv2.imwrite(imagesPath, crop_img)
                self.d+=1
                cv2.rectangle(image,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),color,2)
                cv2.putText(image,label+" "+str(round(confidence,2)),(x,y+30),font,1,(255,255,255),2)


        elapsed_time = time.time() - starting_time
        fps=frame_id/elapsed_time
        cv2.putText(image,"FPS:"+str(round(fps,2)),(10,50),font,2,(0,0,0),1)

        # cv2.imshow("Image",image)
        # key = cv2.waitKey(1) #wait 1ms the loop will start again and we will process the next frame

        # if key == 27: #esc key stops the process
        #     break;
        ret, jpeg = cv2.imencode('.jpg', image)
        return jpeg.tobytes()
```

**index.html**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Object Detection</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Video Streaming Demonstration</h1>
    <img src="{{ url_for('video_feed') }}">
  </body>
</html>
```

**images.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>yolo</title>
</head>
 <body>
   <h1 class="logo">Results</h1>
   <ul>
    {% for data in final_data.files %}
    <li>{{data.label}}</li>
    <img alt="embedded" src="data:image/jpg;base64,{{data.data}}"/>
    {% endfor %}
   </ul>

 </body>
</html>
```